# Dependency injection inside extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, koin, extension-function

Is there a way to inject an object  inside an extension function or a global function using DI framework in Android Kotlin?

I use this function in many places. So I do not want to pass a parameter every time.

DI framework can be any of Koin, Hilt, Dagger2, or others.

Something like that:

```
fun Context.showSomething() {
 val myObject = inject()
 showToast(myObject.text)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking about using `Inject` you could pass it as a parameter:

```
fun Context.showSomething(myObject: String) {
 showToast(myObject.text)
}
```

Comment: I use this function in many places. So I do not want to pass a parameter every time.

Comment: There is very little choice but to either pass in a parameter, or put this method on a class that is constructed instead of on a top-level extension.

Answer (score 0):

With Koin you can do like this,

```
fun Context.showSomething() {
  val myObject = GlobalContext.get().get()
  showToast(myObject.text)
}
```

but it's totally not recommended way of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I use my app component to inject into extension methods. For example, to use `MyInjectableClass` in an extension method:

```
// Your app component
@Component
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun myInjectable(): MyInjectableClass
}

// Your app class
class MyApplication: Application() {
    companion object {
        var appComponent: ApplicationComponent? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create()
    }
}

// Ext.kt file

private val injectable: MyInjectableClass?
    get() = MyApplication.appComponent?.myInjectable()

fun Foo.extension() {
    injectable?.bar()
    // huzzah!
}
```

Of course you still need to provide the `@Provides` or `@Binds` method for `MyInjectableClass`.